# pppd for IPv6 only tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, ipv6, tunnel, pppd

I have this command which works great for IPv4:

```
sudo pppd updetach noauth passive pty "ssh ubuntu@somehost -i ~/somekey.pem -o Batchmode=yes sudo /usr/sbin/pppd nodetach notty noauth" 10.0.0.1:10.0.0.2
```

I want to do the same thing with IPv6 (without IPv4) so I try:

```
sudo pppd updetach noauth passive pty "ssh ubuntu@somehost -i ~/somekey.pem -o Batchmode=yes sudo /usr/sbin/pppd nodetach notty noauth" ipv6 fda3:88f0:3b19:e979::1,fda3:88f0:3b19:e979::2
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
pppd: Illegal interface identifier (local): fda3:88f0:3b19:e979::1
```

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use an EUI-64 address. It's also possible to just put a `,` and not specify the addresses.

The final command looks like:

```
sudo pppd updetach noauth passive pty "ssh ubuntu@somehost -i ~/somekey.pem -o Batchmode=yes sudo /usr/sbin/pppd nodetach notty noauth +ipv6" +ipv6 ipv6 ,
```